# Forgotten Password, need assistance with no grub menu

Tags: 13.10, password

This is my first time using Linux so I'm still new to all this. I have forgotten my admin password, and I've tried opening the grub menu after a reboot, but it doesn't open even after holding down the left shift key. So I think I have the grub bug, but I can't install the fix b/c of not remembering my admin password...so I find myself stuck.... if anyone has any information about this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you have? if it is a USB keyboard try a PS/2 keyboard instead (if you can get hold of one).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/) can help you. Never happened to me so I can't say it will work but the guy who wrote the article seems to be ok.